# How can I run multiple Perl scripts on Windows without opening separate command windows?

Tags: windows, perl

I have as many as ten Perl scripts to run on a Windows server. Is there something better than opening a new prompt for each script and having ten windows open on your server?

Answer (score 4):

You could run them as services.
Look into [Win32::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Daemon-20100921/).

Comment: Nice way if you develop a new application or can change the code.

Answer (score 2):

Run each program in the background. For this, you only need one prompt window. Use the [start](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) command.